# Jquery form validation in submit event triggers another round

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).valid()) {
        $(this).find(".dialogErrorMessageArea").show();
    } else {
        $(this).submit();
    }
});
```

I am trying to bring my custom error message area visible if form is not valid.
However, the else branch now goes back to this handler and never submits. How to submit form in else branch? Or this approach wrong and how to do this correctly?

Comment: put your e.preventDefault(); in the true branch, so it doesn't affect the else branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  if(!$(this).valid()) {
    $(this).find(".dialogErrorMessageArea").show();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

or a bit more simpler:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  if(!$(this).valid()) {
    $(this).find(".dialogErrorMessageArea").show();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply submit form using form attribute:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).valid()) {
        $(this).find(".dialogErrorMessageArea").show();
    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```